# Copying files from corrupt Windows hard drive

Tags: windows-10

I have a laptop drive that failed (clicks upon boot up and says no bootable device exists), however, when I can get it to somewhat work when I hook it up to my desktop computer. Some of the file structure appears and I'm trying to copy files but I'm finding that it's taking forever (days to copy a handful of files). I've tried both command prompt methods (copy/xcopy) and windows, but with same results. Is there a another option that might do less error checking of the copy process that could be quicker?

Comment: Beyond what you've done, the only thing I'd suggest is the iffy, temporary expedient of freezing it; see https://lifehacker.com/5515337/save-a-failed-hard-drive-in-your-freezer-redux .You *might* try making a fault-tolerant image of the HDD and working with the image, rather than the failing drive. Perhaps Macrium Reflect or other image utility would ignore bad spots?

Answer (score -1):

Not a Windows tool but at work and home we use ddrescue. As long as the drive spins ddrescue will recover all data possible. I am getting ready to image a dying msata drive with ddrescue once the new msata shows up. Should have mentioned that ddrescue can is a cloning solution to get your data off the dying drive.

[ddrescue](https://datarecovery.com/rd/how-to-clone-hard-disks-with-ddrescue/)

Another option is Photorec. This will recover as much data as possible. If I remember right I ran photorec once on a clicking drive and it ran about 3 days and recovered as much data as the company we spent $2,000 to recover data. It's a great tool, quite powerful.

[Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)